# How to Reference Items Related to Paper

Tags: citations

I'm not sure how to reference two items related to my current paper. The first is a CSV giving the entries of a 200x200 transition matrix. The second is a web application I developed.

Obviously, the results in the CSV won't fit in the paper. So should I provide a link to it somewhere? If so, how should I go about doing that? And for the web application, should I just provide a link to the website? Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you upload supplemental material?

Comment: I would assume that uploading the CSV somewhere is a must. The matrix itself had to be estimated and is an important result. But I'm just not sure where to upload it and how to reference it. Would Github be ok along with a passing reference?